Primes decomposition in intermediate field
let $F/K$ be a Galois extension, and  $L=K(\alpha)  $ be an intermediate field, $\alpha$ is an algebraic number of $K$. Let $G=\text{Gal}(F/K)$. and let $H=\text{Gal}(F/L)$, and let
$X:=\{ \text{the set of roots of the minimal  polynomial of } \alpha \}$
let $p$ be a prime ideal of $K$, and  $\mathfrak{s}$ denote a prime ideal of $L$  above $p$, and $\mathfrak{q}$ be prime ideal of $F$  above $\mathfrak{s}$.
then the Question is to prove that there is a one-to-one correspondence between
$\{\text{primes } \mathfrak{s} \text{ of } L \text{ above }  p\}$.
and
$D(\mathfrak{q})$-orbits on $X$,
and the size of the orbit is
#$O_\mathfrak{s}
=e(\mathfrak{s}|p) f(\mathfrak{s}|p).$
where $ D(\mathfrak{q}) $ is the decomoposition group of $\mathfrak{q}$
and $e(\mathfrak{s}|p)$ is the ramification index. And $f(\mathfrak{s}|p)$ is the inertia degree.
my attempt
since $F/L$ is Galois we know that $H$ acts transitively on the set of prime ideals above
$\mathfrak{s}$ ideals  in $F$, so when $H$ acts on the set  of all prime ideals above $p$ in $F$ (which are all the prime ideals above all  the $\mathfrak{s}$ ideals) it will split them into distinct orbits where all $\mathfrak{q}$  belonging to the same orbits are above a unique prime ideal  $\mathfrak{s}$ in $L$ hence we get a $1-1$ correspondence between
$\{\text{primes } \mathfrak{s} \text{ of } L \text{ above }  p\}$
and $\{ H \text{-orbits} \text{ of prime ideals above } p \text{ in } F \}$
so it remains to find a map between $H$-orbits of prime ideals above $p$ in $F$ and $D(\mathfrak{q})$-orbits on $X$. but I don't know how to carry on from that

This question is related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737273/decomposition-group-regulates-prime-decomposition-for-non-galois-extensions

Let $L'$ be the Galois closure of $L$ and take $F$ to be $L'$. Identify $X$ with the embeddings $\tau_i : L \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha_i$ for $\alpha_i$ one of the $n$ roots of the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$; then extend each of these embeddings to an automorphism of $L'$. The elements of the quotient $\text{Gal}(L'/K)/D(\mathfrak{q})$ are in bijective correspondence with the primes $P$ of $L'$ lying over $p$. The elements of this quotient with representative $\tau_i$ for some $i$ correspond bijectively to the $D(\mathfrak{q})$-orbits on $X$. For $\tau_i D(\mathfrak{q})$, consider its orbit under the action of $H = \text{Gal}(L'/L)$. If the orbit contains $\tau_j D(\mathfrak{q})$ for some $\tau_j \neq \tau_i$, then $\tau_j = h\tau_i$. But then $\tau_j\tau_i^{-1} = h$, so $\tau_j\tau_i^{-1}$ fixes $\alpha$. This in turn implies that $\tau_j(L) = \tau_i(L)$, a contradiction since $i \neq j$. Therefore, for each $\tau_i$, which we've identified with a particular element of $X$, the element $\tau_i D(\mathfrak{q})$ corresponds to a unique $H$-orbit on $\text{Gal}(L'/K)/D(\mathfrak{q})$. Since $\text{Gal}(L'/K)/D(\mathfrak{q})$ corresponds bijectively with the primes of $L'$ lying above $p$, by what you've already shown we have an injective correspondence of the $D(\mathfrak{q})$-orbits on $X$ into the set of primes in $L$ lying above $p$. One then deduces that this correspondence is in fact bijective from the following:

Each orbit of $H$ in $D(\mathfrak{q})$ consists of $[L' : L]$-many elements.

There are $n = [L : K]$ elements $\tau_i$.

Each orbit of $H$ contains at most one element of the form $\tau_i D(\mathfrak{q})$.


The sizes of the orbits follows from the fact that $[L : K] = \sum_{i = 1}^n e(\mathfrak{p}_i|p)f(\mathfrak{p}_i |p)$, where $i$ indexes the set of primes in $L$ lying above $p$.
